# Detect th value from table click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table>
    <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Bob</td>
            <td>300 Wacker Drive</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If I click on Bob, I want to get back the value "Name". How can I do this using jQuery?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Off topic: *"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. on click of `td`

```
var thVal = $(this).closest('table').find('th').eq( this.cellIndex).text();
alert(thVal);
```

Comment: forgot `.text()` at the end ^.^

Comment: Forgot to get the text() and you might want to show how to add the click. `$("table tbody").on("click", "td", function(){ ...} );`

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ  gotcha ..gotcha..feeling great :)

Answer (score 0):

I did this fiddle to simulate an ajax call over a table but I think work pretty much for you case http://jsfiddle.net/ncubica/Umxjb/

in you case you can change the `data-id` attribute to `data-name="bob"` and request the value with `$target.attr("data-name")`

html

```
<i style='display:none' id="loadingPopup">Loading</i>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td data-id="td1"> row 1</td>
    </tr>        
   <tr>        
        <td data-id="td2"> row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-id="td3"> row 3</td>
    </tr>        
</table>
```

JS

```
$("table").on("click", function(event){
    var $target = $(event.target); 
    if($target.is("td")){
        var id = $target.attr("data-id");
        makeAjax(id);
    }
});

//simulating ajax

function makeAjax(id){
    //you will have to use ajax an retrieve you json format
    //i will simulate ajax only
    $("#loadingPopup").show();
    var _json = { id : id, value : "some value", description : "some description"};
    setTimeout(function(){response(_json)}, 1000);
}

function response(_json){
    $("#loadingPopup").hide();    
    alert(_json.id + " - " + _json.value);
}
```

CSS

```
table{font-family:arial; font-size:12px; width:100%}
table tr td{border-bottom:1px solid #CCC; padding:10px; 100%}
```

Happy coding!!